# как задать значение textarea в Spring form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
 <form:form action="/editComment" method="post" class="form-horizontal" 
     modelAttribute="commentEntity">
     <form:textarea class="form-control" path="comment"/>
 </form:form>
```

есть форма, для редактирования комментария, как с помощью спринг задать значение textarea?
если делать так то значение не выводит:

```
 <form:form action="/editComment" method="post" class="form-horizontal" 
         modelAttribute="commentEntity">
         <form:textarea class="form-control" path="comment" value="${comment}">
         </form:form>
```

если сделать так: `<form:textarea class="form-control" path="comment">${comment}</form:textarea>`
кидает ошибку : [form:textarea] must be empty, but is not

Comment: Здесь уже ответили на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380865/spring-tag-formtextarea-must-be-empty-but-is-not-error

Comment: @РостиславКрасный да да я